# Insert Random silence multiple times between Audios in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

suppose I have MP3 of around 1 minute duration and increase its duration longer.Duration can be any.

I want to randomly add N seconds of silence to that audio.

I can generate the silence like below

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=mono -t <seconds> -q:a 9 -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3
```

And I can insert silence to audio like below

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -filter_complex "anullsrc,atrim=0:4[s];[0]atrim=0:14[a];[0]atrim=14,asetpts=N/SR/TB[b];[a][s][b]concat=3:v=0:a=1" out.wav
```

Is there anyway to insert silence at multiple areas.With php I can generate random time to insert based on 60 seconds audio like below.

```
$arr = [];
$arr[3] = 2; //here 3 is original audio insert time and 2 is the duration of silence
$arr[6] = 3;  //here 6 is original audio insert time and 3 is the duration of silence
$arr[10] = 1;
$arr[12] = 3;
```

Now I want to insert silence between seconds based on above array  like

```
2 seconds silence at 3rd second
3 seconds silence at 6th second
1 second silence at 10th second
```

and son on..

Comment: Is the duration of silence chosen by you or some random process? Is the location of insertion chosen by you or some random process?

Comment: Hi , right now I am generating the randomness via php , you can see the array thats  generated.

Comment: I can run for loop with duration and location and generate some ffmpeg code aswel.(by concatenation)

Answer (score 2):

I assume the location and duration of silences are known to you before ffmpeg execution.

Using as an example,

```
2 seconds silence at 3rd second
3 seconds silence at 6th second
1 second silence at 10th second
```

you would run

`ffmpeg -i in.wav -af "asetpts='PTS+gte(T\,2)*2/TB+gte(T\,5)*3/TB+gte(T\,9)*1/TB',aresample=async=1" out.wav`

The asetpts filter preserves the timestamps of the interval 0 to 2. It increases timestamps of all frames with timestamp 2s or higher by 2 seconds. It further adds 3 seconds to all frames with timestamp >= 5, and another second to all timestamps 9 and higher. `T` refers to source timestamps.

The `aresample` filter then plugs all timestamp gaps with silence.

Comment: Thanks but In my for loop  where do I update the location.. duration i can change here i guess *2/TB , *3/TB  , *1/TB

Comment: It got 2 ,5 and , 8.. but . i have 3 , 6 and 10.. its little confusing

Comment: `3rd second` means `T=2`

Comment: ok its should be minus 1 ? got it :) let me try

Comment: Thanks can add some fade in fade out between these silence ?